# Embed large json file in single index elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I embed json file in elasticsearch with large data nearly 300k records. I am using shell script but with this i am not able to load more than 4000 records.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying?

Comment: I need to add a json file which has nearly 300 thousands of json records. I have to add that into elasticsearch